# HTTP Request from WebScript in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, web-scripting

I'm writing a WebScript in Alfresco using JS controller and I want to make a HTTP request to the local HTTP resource. This resource is a Java-based app and gives me its own REST API.

My WebScript is not a Share Component: so I don't have a `remote` object to call another webscript.

How can I make a HTTP request to the local resource (something like '/sdo/documents/getName?type=fl') from a WebScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Alfresco is overriding the Spring Surf `webscripts.container` bean removing the `remote` definition (in `web-scripts-application-context.xml` of `remote-api`):

```
<bean id="webscripts.container" class="org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer" parent="webscripts.abstractcontainer">
      <property name="name"><value>Repository</value></property>
      <property name="scriptObjects">
         <map merge="true">
           <entry key="paging">
              <ref bean="webscripts.js.paging"/>
           </entry>
         </map>
<!-- ..... -->
</bean>
```

I suggest you include it again as a [custom Javascript API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#Adding_Custom_Script_APIs) root level object.

---

The `remote` root object comes from the [Spring Surf](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-surf) framework, meaning you have it regardless of being developing your Web Scripts against the Alfresco repository or Share. As a proof, here's the source for [a Web Script](http://cmis.alfresco.com/service/script/org/alfresco/cmis/sample/cmisrepo.get) available in the public Alfresco CMIS server (-> Alfresco repository instance, admin/admin if you are asked to login):

```
var serviceUrl = (args.service === null) ? "/api/repository" : args.service;
var conn = remote.connect("alfresco");
var result = conn.get(stringUtils.urlEncodeComponent(serviceUrl));

var service = atom.toService(result.response);
var workspace = service.workspaces.get(0);
model.repo = workspace.getExtension(atom.names.cmisra_repositoryInfo);
```

The following snippet is taken from `spring-surf-application-context.xml` as found inside `spring-webscripts-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar` of Alfresco 3.4.0, which is where the `remote` root object gets its definition:

```
   <bean id="webscripts.container" parent="webscripts.abstractcontainer" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.LocalWebScriptRuntimeContainer">
      <property name="name"><value>Spring Surf Container</value></property>
      <property name="registry" ref="webscripts.registry" />
      <property name="searchPath" ref="webframework.webscripts.searchpath" />
      <property name="templateProcessorRegistry" ref="webframework.webscripts.registry.templateprocessor" />
      <property name="scriptProcessorRegistry" ref="webframework.webscripts.registry.scriptprocessor" />
      <property name="scriptParameterFactoryRegistry" ref="webscripts.web.scriptparameterfactoryregistry" />
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
      <property name="scriptObjects">
         <map merge="true">
            <entry key="remote" value-ref="webframework.webscripts.scriptremote" />
         </map>
      </property>
      <property name="processorModelHelper" ref="processor.model.helper"/>
      <property name="extensibilityModuleHandler" ref="webscripts.extensibility.handler"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="webframework.webscripts.scriptremote" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptRemote">
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config"/>
      <property name="connectorProvider" ref="webframework.connector.provider"/>
   </bean>
```

Comment: I've tried to use the `remote` object in my WebScript: `var result = remote.connect("http").get("/t3sdo/enum/get?type=" + field.value);`. But I've got an error `"remote" is not defined`. What is wrong? PS: it is not Spring Surf level, it is just an alfresco webscript.

Comment: [Web Scripts](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M3/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts-documentation/reference/index.html) are a module of Spring Surf. Which version of Alfresco are you running?

Comment: 3.4.0 and I'm speaking about scripts with URL `/alfresco/service/...`, not Surf Components where the `remote` is available.

Comment: As I already said, Web Scripts are part of Spring Surf. I understand you're not writing a Surf Component script, but this doesn't mean you're not within the context of Spring Surf.

Comment: I found out why `remote` is not available, and updated the answer to describe a possible solution.

Comment: I changed `web-scripts-application-context.xml` by adding there the snippet from `spring-webscripts-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar` you wrote before, but Alfresco threw the exception `No bean named 'webframework.connector.provider' is defined` and stopped.

Comment: So I've solved my problem other way without using remote calls from Web Script, but the `remote` object is not available yet. :( Anyway thank you, skuro!