# create flattened folder alias in alfresco

Tags: javascript, directory, alfresco

I am not extremely well versed in Javascript. Nonetheless i need to find a way to create a webscript for Alfresco that creates an alias [A] of a folder(space) [B].

If [B] looks like companyhome/site/special/my/fo/ld/de/r,

[A] should look like companyhome/site/myfolder

and be an alias (secondary node parent?) pointing to [B].

I´d like this webscript to be executed whenever a new folder is created under  `companyhome/site/special/`

Comment: How would this be executed when a folder is created?  Are you running something like node.js with a file watcher on that folder?

Comment: The Folder watching will be done by Alfresco Folder Action (Rule). So that every time a new folder is created, Alfresco runs a Webscript which contains the js

Comment: I don't konw anything about Alfresco, but if this is web-based, then there seems little liklihood of creating an alias in the *nix sense of a soft directory link.  If you just want a link on a web page which your web server will interpret properly that doesn't sound too hard.  But it's simply not clear to me where you're headed.

Comment: What about https://github.com/skomarica/alfresco-share-create-link

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to execute a webscript? If you write some JavaScript utilising the repository JavaScript API and drop this into Company Home > Data Dictionary > Scripts, then you can trigger this to run based on a rule.

If you really need to call out to an external URL then you can follow the method documented in [HTTP Request from WebScript in Alfresco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282660/http-request-from-webscript-in-alfresco) to do this from your JavaScript action.